# svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to DELETE request for

Tags: svn

I am getting following error when committing.

`svn: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to DELETE request for '/repository/XXREPOXX/!svn/act/d8f0d94a-8a6c-4986-b757-7a3e469190b9'`

If I do `svn update` after the error I get the my commit with new revision no and with status G.

My other team mates can do commits without a problem and they are on windows. I am on Ubuntu 11.04 and with subversion version - version 1.6.12 (r955767). 
But I can work/commit to other repositories on other servers without any problem

Any help to solve this is appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, just a fairly wild guess, but have you checked file permissions?

Comment: I just checked with giving all permission (777) but didn't work that. Does subversion store permissions?

Comment: No, I don't mean check your local permissions.  I mean check that the subversion daemon has write privs to the repo.  I actually doubt it's the problem, but worth checking.  (Though if you know others can commit to the repo, it's not file perms.  I'm assuming though that you meant that they can commit to other repos.)

Comment: subversion daemon has correct permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own. This has occurred because of my ISP's proxy settings. Not anything of my or svn server's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are not commiting to a file that's locked